# Expose controller's class method to view helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How do I make the following method available in the view layer?

```
# app/controllers/base_jobs_controller.rb
class BaseJobsController < ApplicationController
  def self.filter_name
    (controller_name.singularize + "_filter").to_sym
  end
end
```

I want to use it in a view helper like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def filter_link(text, options = {})
    # Need access to filter_name in here....
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `helper_method`, I prefer to include such functionality in a module.

```
module BaseJobsHelp
  def filter_name
    (controller_name.singularize + "_filter").to_sym
  end
end
```

Then include the module in the `BaseJobsController` and `ApplicationHelper`.

```
class BaseJobsController < ApplicationController
  include BaseJobsHelp

  # ...
end


module ApplicationHelper
  include BaseJobsHelp

  def filter_link(text, options = {})
    # You can access filter_name without trouble
  end
end
```

Depending on the content of your methods in the module, you may need to use an alternative method to access certain data *(ie. the current controller's name)*.